# Generic interface that forces fields

Tags: typescript, generics

We use this pattern a lot:

```
export const isMissing = (s: State): s is None | Token => s.type < StateTypes.PRESENT;
```

We would like to have something similar for fields inside interfaces. I'll explain - imagine a type like this:

```
export interface Role extends Identifiable {
  readonly type: RoleType;
  readonly name: string;
  readonly profile: RoleProfile;
  readonly ethAddress?: string;
  readonly ethSignature?: Application;
}
```

We would like a function to act as a type guard on certain fields based on another interface that has these fields non-optional. For example:

```
interface EthInfo<T> {
  readonly [name: K keyof T]: T[K];
  readonly ethAddress: string;
  readonly ethSignature: Application;
}
```

And then have a function guard allowing something like this:

```
export const isEthContainer<T> = (obj: T): s is EthInfo<T> =>
  (pseudo code that checks that all non-optional fields of EthInfo are at least optional in T and are not undefined in the instance of T obj);
```

So we could use it like so:

```
if (!isEthContainer(role)) { return; }
// At this point, role.ethAddress and role.ethSignature would be guaranteed not to be undefined.
```

The goal is to have enough genericity to have not just one interface have `ethAddress` and `ethSignature` - so the construct must work generically.

Also, the example is simplified - in our case `Role` contains many more fields which are set in groups based on the user permissions, so we would declare other interfaces similar to the `EthInfo<T>` one.

Is there a known pattern for achieving this?

Comment: Do you just want `type EthInfo<T> = Readonly<T> & {readonly ethAddress: string; readonly ethSignature: Application}`?  It's hard to know if this meets your use case without a [mcve] that doesn't refer to undeclared types/values.

Comment: I've put together something to look at. It's at https://codepen.io/hickscorp/pen/qBBebLq
Basically, we would like to avoid having to declare `EthFields` and `EthOptionalFields` twice, and then having to check each field in the `hasEthInfo` function.
Ideally, we would have an interface listing the fields once, have a way of saying "Extend them *as optional* in Role", and have some kind of meta-programming in `hasEthInfo` which would automatically check each field existence without having to manually list them.

Comment: So use `Partial<EthFields>` instead of `EthOptionalFields`?  Or use `Required<EthOptionalFields>` instead of `EthFields`?  Also, please put your [mcve] directly in the question so people don't have to leave SO to see it (see [ask]).